# Python mechanize Browser.links() - strange behaviour

Tags: python, browser, mechanize

I'm new to mechanize in python and it would be nice if someone could explain why this happens?

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
a = br.open('http://www.google.co.in')
links = br.links()
for link in links:
    print link.url
```

However when I do this again, nothing gets printed out

```
 for link in links:
    print link.url
```

Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My best guess would be that maybe `br.links()` returns a generator. And that means that it doesn't return one big iterable, but is dynamic and waits for the `next` to be called on it before returning the next value in the sequence, so unless you store the variable yourself into a `list`, then it is only usable once.

Comment: +1 for picking up the 'again' in the question; it is slightly subtle with the way it is phrased that the OP is trying to iterate twice.

Comment: and indeed `type(links)` gives `<type 'generator'>`

Comment: @manoj if you found notbag.jpeg's answer helpful, you should [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).